# I can not restrict fields even when use find projection in mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a problem with projection in find method mongodb nodejs. My results contain all fields.

See code below:

I want to have only name and age fields. I test code below and some combinations as well.

```
db.db("TodoApp").collection("Users").find(
    {
        Age:{$lte:20},       
        $and:[{Name:{$in:["Gh","dd","Mahdi"]}},{Location:"Mashhad"}]
    },
    {
        _id:0,
        Name:1,
        Age:1,
    }).toArray().then((docs)=>{
        console.log("Users");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(docs,undefined,2));
    },(error)=>{
        console.log("Unable to fetch Users");
    }) ;
```

The result is the same: you can see jsons below

```
Users
[


{
    "_id": "5a4010d286d6152734f13f00",
    "Name": "Mahdi",
    "Location": "Mashhad",
    "Age": 20
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a4010d286d6152734f13f01",
    "Name": "Gh",
    "Location": "Mashhad",
    "Age": 20
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a401115c7320c1e0400b692",
    "Name": "Mahdi",
    "Location": "Mashhad",
    "Age": 20
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a40116cbf000c2128670648",
    "Name": "Mahdi",
    "Location": "Mashhad",
    "Age": 20
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a401174da2a7127b8b649d7",
    "Name": "Mahdi",
    "Location": "Mashhad",
    "Age": 20
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a401174da2a7127b8b649d8",
    "Name": "Mahdi",
    "Location": "Mashhad",
    "Age": 18
  }
]
```

I tested a lot of queries but still exists the problem

```
db.db("TodoApp").collection("Users").find(query8,{Name:0}).toArray((error,result)=>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result,undefined,2));
});


db.db("TodoApp").collection("Users").find(query8,{Name:1}).toArray((error,result)=>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result,undefined,2));
    });
```

result contains all fields.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I want to have only name and age fields for example

Comment: you cannot mix those 0s and 1s. only _id can be mixed, others are either all 1s or all 0s

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/

Comment: I test it and combinations always get all fields.I use mongodb3.6

Answer (score 1):

```
var query8={
     Location:null
 }
var prj={
    _id:0,
    Name:1
};

db.db("TodoApp").collection("Users").find(query8).project(prj).toArray((error,result)=>{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result,undefined,2));
});
```

output:

```
Connected to mongodb server
[
  {
    "Name": "Ghazanfar"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Sara"
  }
]
```

when I use project(), it is ok and there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.

So if you want only age and name you need to use;

```
{
    _id:0,
    Name:1,
    Age:1
}
```

But if you don't want to see location;

```
{
   Location:0
}
```

Comment: I know it but you can see it returns all fields like shown above